# Swing slider not showing up

Tags: java, swing, slider

I'm trying to add a slider to my frame using JSwing components, but for some reason it's not working. I tried looking up possible solutions but they either don't apply or haven't worked for me such as setting the size or visibility and what not. Basically, why doesn't my slider show up?

I've got a carIcon that shows up just fine, but the slider won't. Here's my code.

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Slider Tester");

    MoveableShape shape = new CarShape(125, 100, CAR_WIDTH);
    slider bar = new slider();

    ShapeIcon icon = new ShapeIcon(shape,
        ICON_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT);

    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(label);
    frame.add(bar);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocation(100,100);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

and my slider

```
public class slider extends JPanel implements ChangeListener
{

    private JSlider carSlider;

    public slider()
    {
    carSlider = new JSlider();
    carSlider.addChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The slider is not added to the panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `slider` is not added to the panel. 
Add this line to `slider` constructor:

```
add(carSlider);
```

Comment: It shows that I really have no experience. Plus, for me, it's hard to understand the Oracle tutorials. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So, when were you intending to add the slider??

```
public slider()
{
    carSlider = new JSlider();
    carSlider.addChangeListener(this);
}
```

Creates the slider nicely, but does nothing with it...

```
public slider()
{
    carSlider = new JSlider();
    carSlider.addChangeListener(this);
    add(carSlider); // <-- Look and me, I'm new :D
}
```

Will work better

Comment: @Max Yeah, but I think you're comment beat me!

Comment: I'd accept yours as an answer too, seeing how it's the same, but Max beat you to it. Thank you though.